# HTTP status 404 (error) when trying to log in

Tags: 404-error

I've changed the `http://` host `to https://`, then accidentally saved it. Now I can't log in to the admin panel having '404 Not Found' page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: if you have access to phpmyadmin, you need to update your database ( http://.... to https://.... ),

Answer (score 0):

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Add this to your `wp-config.php` which you can find in the root of your website. Remember to change `example.com` to your URL.

Answer (score -1):

Before I start, I should point out that I am making a few educated guesses about what you have done exactly. I will try to cover as much as I can. This is most likely an issue with the way your hosting is set up. WP.SE is not the ideal question to ask about that. However, depending on how comfortable you are with accessing the database itself, you should be able to locate the entry and revert your changes.

If you have access to your database, say with PHPMyAdmin, you can look for the wp_options table. In there you can find the rows with `option_name` "siteurl" & "home". You could then edit the `option_value` to reflect the hostname you require. More help on doing that [can be found here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-How-do-I-change-the-WordPress-Site-URL-). There are plenty of search results you could also help, but this was one of the first ones I found.

If you made the change to your options file, you will need to use FTP or your hosting file editor to revert your changes.

That said, you may wish to look at how your hosting provider assigns HTTPS and check that it is enabled, pointed at the same folder and has a valid certificate. You'd have to take to hosting support if you need help with that.